# RxJs avoid external state but still access previous values

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm using RxJs to listen to a amqp queu (not really relevant).

I have a function `createConnection` that returns an `Observable` that emits the new **connection** object. Once I have a connection, I want to send messages through it every **1000ms** and after 10 messages I want to close the connection.

I'm trying to avoid external state, but if I don't store the connection in an external variable, how can I close it? See I begin with the connection, then `flatMap` and push messages, so after a few chains I no longer have the connection object.

This is no my flow but imagine something like this:

```
createConnection()
  .flatMap(connection => connection.createChannel())
  .flatMap(channel => channel.send(message))
  .do(console.log)
  .subscribe(connection => connection.close()) <--- obviously connection isn't here
```

Now I understand that it's stupid to do that, but now how do I access the connection? I could of course begin with `var connection = createConnection()`

and later on somehow join that. But how do I do this? I don't even know how to ask this question properly. Bottomline, what I have is an observable, that emits a connection, after the connection is opened I want an observable that emits messages every 1000ms (with a `take(10)`), then close the connection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is "you can carry it through each step". For example, you can replace this line

```
.flatMap(connection => connection.createChannel())
```

with this one:

```
.flatMap(connection => ({ connection: connection, channel: connection.createChannel() }))
```

and retain access to the connection all the way down.

But there's another way to do what you want to do. Let's assume your createConnection and createChannel functions look something like this:

```
function createConnection() {
  return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    console.log('creating connection');
    const connection = {
      createChannel: () => createChannel(),
      close: () => console.log('disposing connection')
    };

    observer.onNext(connection);

    return Rx.Disposable.create(() => connection.close());
  });
}

function createChannel() {
  return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    const channel = {
      send: x => console.log('sending message: ' + x)
    };

    observer.onNext(channel);

    // assuming no cleanup here, don't need to return disposable
  });
}
```

`createConnection` (and `createChannel`, but we'll focus on the former) returns a cold observable; each subscriber will get their own connection stream containing a single connection, and when that subscription expires, the dispose logic will be called automatically.

This allows you to do something like this:

```
const subscription = createConnection()
  .flatMap(connection => connection.createChannel())
  .flatMap(channel => Rx.Observable.interval(1000).map(i => ({ channel: channel, data: i })))
  .take(10)
  .subscribe(x => x.channel.send(x.data))
;
```

You don't actually have to dispose the subscription for cleanup to occur; after `take(10)` is satisfied, the whole chain will finish and cleanup will be triggered. The only reason you'd need to call dispose on the subscription explicitly is if you wanted to tear things down before the 10 1000ms intervals were up.

Note that this solution also contains an instance of the direct answer to your question: we cart the channel down the line so we can use it in the onNext lambda passed to the subscribe call (which is customarily where such code would appear).

Here's the whole thing working: https://jsbin.com/korihe/3/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Great answer, thanks Matt. Could you maybe elaborate on how the connection gets disposed? I'm guessing is the `return Rx.Disposable.create(() => console.log('disposing connection'));` but I don't quite understand how the cleanup logic triggers that.

Comment: Sorry, I totally skipped over that part! I've updated my answer to make things more clear.

Comment: Actually, I may have missed the point of your previous comment; I had skipped over the wiring (which I've now replaced), but reading more carefully it sounded like you were asking how the dispose itself is triggered. Let me know if so, and I'll elaborate on that.

Comment: yes that's what I meant hehe. I don't know about Disposables or how that actually happens. because after observer.onNext() you return that. Also, if I wanted to share a connection, I would probably need a hot observable and an AsyncSubject? because if so I don't think I'd be able to pull off this trick.

Comment: It's a good idea to go through the doco on the various Disposable types in rxjs, as they provide good patterns for cleanup. In general, when subscriptions complete or are explicitly disposed, any disposal logic associated with the observable will be triggered. Observable.create allows such cleanup logic to be specified by returning an instance of Disposable. There are calls such as "share" which allow you to share a single subscription to an underlying cold observable, so you can still use this approach.

Answer (score -1):

This code gave me a error because flatmap wait for a **observable<(T)>** and **({ connection: connection, channel: connection.createChannel() }**) it's a Object.

`.flatMap(connection => ({ connection: connection, channel: connection.createChannel() }))`

instead you can use the **combineLatest** operator

`.flatMap(connection => Observable.combineLatest( Observable.of(connection), connection.createChannel(), (connection, channel) => {
               ... code .... 
});`