# Observable Race Condition, how to time two Observables correctly

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have an obeservable sequence, where each time a call release event occurs I map that event to an http request that returns a callog json Array.

I need to combine the value emitting form the call event with the json array. However by the time the json array has returned the call event Observable has emitted a new value.

```
const agentCallEventStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(call realease event)
const agentCallLogStream = agentCallEventStream.flatMap( (agentObj) => {
       return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(callLogHelper.getUserCallLogs(agentObj.agentId));
      }

        // I tried this 
    const callLogMerged = agentCallLogStream.combineLatest(agentCallEventStream)

// but the event data returned is newer than the call log data returned
```

Im looking for an operator or some way to keep the data in sync

Comment: can you do a marble diagram with input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to merge the same `agentObj` that generated the promise, you can carry it in the selector function directly. You will find a good example from that SO's question : [RxJs avoid external state but still access previous values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612519/rxjs-avoid-external-state-but-still-access-previous-values/36625458#36625458)

```
agentCallEventStream.flatMap( (agentObj) => 
                {       
                  Rx.Observable.fromPromise(callLogHelper.getUserCallLogs(agentObj.agentId))
                    .map(function (promiseValue){return {
                         promise : promiseValue, 
                         agentObj : agentObj
                        }});
                 }
```

If that's not what you want, you should specify clearly in a marble diagram what are the input and expected outputs.

**UPDATE** : following paulpadniels comment, here is a shorter version using `flatMap` with result selector function :

```
agentCallEventStream.flatMap( 
    (agentObj) => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(callLogHelper.getUserCallLogs(agentObj.agentId)),
    (promiseValue) => {promise : promiseValue, agentObj : agentObj}
)
```

Truth is this signature of [`flatMap`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md) is rarely used, but it should be when possible as it is more performant (avoids creating extra inner observables and subscriptions) and more expressive.

Comment: Thats exactly what im looking for , Working on a marble diagram now, and will provide one for future questions, Thank you

Comment: Hint: You can simplify and use the secondary selector of `flatMap` instead of nesting a `map`